# E: Unable to locate package ipython3

Tags: apt, package-management

I wanted to install ipython3

I entered

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3
```

but I got this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ipython3
```

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update` first

Answer (score 0):

do this first

```
sudo apt-get update
```